# How to get equidistant discrete points on y-axis with a loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to get equidistant discrete points on y-axis with a loop? I have done without loop. Please make a loop for this.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%x=2cm,y=2cm
        dot/.style = {circle, fill,
                      minimum size=.02ex,
                      }
                            ]
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (-5,0)--(5,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (0,-5)--(0,5) node [above] {$y$};
    %
    \foreach \Point [count=\i] in {
    (0,-5),(0,-4.5),(0,-4), (0,-3.5), (0,-3), (0,-2.5), (0,-2), (0,-1.5), (0,-1), (0,-.5), (0,0),
    (0,5),(0,4.5),(0,4), (0,3.5), (0,3), (0,2.5), (0,2), (0,1.5), (0,1), (0,.5)
    }
    {
     \node[dot] at \Point {};
    }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%x=2cm,y=2cm
        dot/.style = {circle, fill,
                      inner sep=.2ex,
                      }
                            ]
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (-5,0)--(5,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (0,-5)--(0,5) node [above] {$y$};
    %
    \path foreach \Y in {-10,...,9}
    {(0,\Y/2) coordinate[dot]};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use special foreach syntax:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=.02ex, } ]
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (-5,0)--(5,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thin, draw=gray] (0,-5)--(0,5) node [above] {$y$}; %
    \foreach \y in {-5, -4.5,..., 5} { \node[dot] at (0,\y) {}; } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```